# How to use dynamic style class in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am getting the style class from Rest Web Service.

```
 try {
      var securityTokenInBean = {
        securityToken: authToken
      };
      fetchPost(
        "monitorprobe/getAllMonitoringProbe",
        "POST",
        securityTokenInBean,
        json => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            sumUp: json.sumUp,
            styleClass : json.styleClass
          });
          this.state.isLoading = false;
        },
        err => {
          console.log("needToCallBack: api call failed." + err);
          //error(this.props.navigation,'error in needToCallBack ws call');
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("needToCallBack: api call failed." + error);
    }
```

I need to use the style class in my View component. The value of styleClass is either criticalProbe,issueProbe,warningProbe,expiredProbe or okProbe

I have defined the styles for the all the classed defined in my StyleSheet.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

criticalProbe : {
  backgroundColor: 'black',

},

issueProbe : {
  backgroundColor: 'red',

},
warningProbe : {
  backgroundColor: 'orange',

},

expiredProbe : {
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
},

okProbe : {
  backgroundColor: 'green',

}

});
```

How do I use the styleClass in my View Component which comes from rest service as the style class is Dynamic?

I tried with

```
const criticalProbeStyleClass = styleClass.criticalProbeStyleClass;
console.log(criticalProbeStyleClass);//comes as okProbe
<View style={[styles.box, styles.criticalProbeStyleClass ]}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Critical</Text>
            <Text style={styles.criticalProbeStyleClass}>{sumUp.totalCriticalProbe}</Text>
         </View>
```

But it does not work.

To verify I have tried with by hard coding style class and looks fine

```
<View style={[styles.box, styles.okProbe]}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Critical</Text>
            <Text style={styles.criticalProbeStyleClass}>{sumUp.totalCriticalProbe}</Text>
         </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request returning just a name for the style property;

Create a file including all your styling that you want (*`globalStyles.js` for example*) and export it. In the component you want to use import it. Then you can use the file shown like below.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  criticalProbe : {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  issueProbe : {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  warningProbe : {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  expiredProbe : {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  okProbe : {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  }
});

export default styleClasses;
```

---

```
<View style={[styles.box, styleClasses[styleClass.criticalProbeStyleClass] ]}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>Critical</Text>
  <Text style={styles.criticalProbeStyleClass}>{sumUp.totalCriticalProbe}</Text>
</View>
```